# A problem of four conics

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, curves, conic-sections

I found a remarkable theorem of four conics as follows [some years ago](http://oaithanhdao.blogspot.com/2014/10/80-another-four-conics-theorem.html). But it has no proof; I am looking for a proof:

**Theorem:** *Take three conics. Suppose that each of them touch a fourth conic at two points. Then remaining pair of common tangents intersect at three collinear points.*

[image]

Comment: Why do you call it a theorem if it has no proof?

Comment: Yes, maybe call it is problem

Comment: This is dual to 11.1.26 in Arseniy Akopyan's book "Geometry in Figures", but there is no proof either.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev  have only the old version, can you send me the Figure?

Comment: This is just the dual: tangent conics remain tangent conics, common tangent lines become intersection points, so the claim is that the lines of three common secants meet at a point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a consequence of the [Double Contact Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleContactTheorem.html).

> If $S_1$, $S_2$, and $S_3$ are three conics having the property that there
> is a point $X$, not on any of the conics, lying on a common chord of
> each pair of the three conics (with the chords in question being
> distinct), then there exists a conic $S_4$ that has a double contact
> with each of $S_1$, $S_2$, and $S_3$ (Evelyn et al. 1974, p. 18).
>
> The converse of the theorem states that if three conics $S_1$, $S_2$, and
> $S_3$ all have double contact with another $S_4$ then each two of $S_1$,
> $S_2$, and $S_3$ have a "distinguished" pair of opposite common chords,
> the three such pairs of common chords being the pairs of opposite
> sides of a complete quadrangle (Evelyn et al. 1974, p. 19).
>
> The dual theorems are stated as follows. If three conics are such
> that, taken by pairs, they have couples of common tangents
> intersecting at three distinct points on a line (that is not itself a
> tangent to any of the conics), then (a) the conics have this property
> in four different ways, and (b) the conics all have double contact
> with a fourth. And, conversely, if three conics each have double
> contact with a fourth, then certain of their common tangents intersect
> by pairs at the vertices of a complete quadrilateral (Evelyn et al.
> 1974, p. 22).

Your observation is the last sentence of the quote above.  This is all proven in  *The Seven Circles Theorem and Other New Theorems* by Evelyn et al.  The proof is a couple of pages which I won't reproduce here, manipulating equations of lines and conics and their pencils to get the desired result.  A hardcore synthetic proof would have been more satisfying, but equation chasing may be more efficient.

The six tangents form a hexagon, so the tangent intersections are on a Pascal line, and the vertices of the hexagon would lie on their own conic.

**Update:** The theorem goes back to at least 1863, because it can be found in [Salmon, *Conic Sections*, Art. 306, pg 267](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_q8VUeQNZhCsC/page/n285/mode/2up): "Or, three conics, having each double contact with a fourth, may be considered as having four axes of similitude. (See Art. 117, of which this theorem is an extension.)"

**Update 2:** Going back even earlier, the theorem is in the [1850 edition of Salmon's Conics ($\S 264$)](https://archive.org/details/treatiseoncon2ed00salmuoft/page/220/mode/2up).